# NGINX Proxy Manager cannot resolve locations

Tags: dns, nginx, reverse-proxy, npm

***Please read Update below***

**My setup:**

[image: Overview]

**My goal:**

Access Heimdall at `https://heimdall.myserver.lan` instead of `https://myserver.lan:8444/`.

**My configuration:**

I've set up a freshly installed NPM at `http://myserver.lan:8185/` which is a Docker container made with Portainer on a Debian VM inside a Promox VE server.

I've got Heimdall ready at `https://myserver:8444/` which is a Docker container as well. SSL is managed by Heimdall itself.

**This is my NPM Proxy Host config:**

[image: NPM Proxy Host config]

[image: NPM Proxy Host overview]

When I click on `heimdall.myserver.lan` the browser opens the location correctly but no server can be found: "We can’t connect to the server at heimdall.myserver.lan."

**These are the locations which I can access directly in my browser:**

Heimdall:
`https://myserver:8444/`
`https://myserver.lan:8444/`

NPM:
`http://myserver:8185/`
`http://myserver.lan:8185/`

Apache container:
`http://myserver:8080`
`http://myserver.lan:8080`

**I can shell into the NPM container:**

```
# docker container exec -it npm /bin/bash
# cat /etc/hostname
a521690d0bd0

# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.9      a521690d0bd0

# cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain lan
search lan
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

**Ping works for:**

```
myserver / myserver.lan
myrouter / myrouter.lan
a521690d0bd0 (the localhost)
```

**But not for:**

```
a521690d0bd0.lan
d4fa6db15d5e
d4fa6db15d5e.lan (the heimdall container)
```

I could certainly add `a521690d0bd0.lan` to `/etc/hosts` but I guess that won't matter.

I thought maybe just the other docker containers aren't reachable but it's the same with Apache at `http://myserver.lan:80` This is not a container, it's a regular Apache on myserver.lan.

No external access is required. It's all in my homelab. AdGuard Home is the DNS server in my OpenWrt router. There are two rules:

```
[/lan/]127.0.0.1:5353
[//]127.0.0.1:5353
```

I did this once to be able to resolve all my local hostnames because the DHCP server is kept inside OpenWrt itself.

**What am I missing here? What's the next step to troubleshoot?**

## Update:

I managed to update my DNS with a CNAME record like this:

```
config cname
        option cname 'heimdall.myserver.lan'
        option target 'myserver.lan'
```

Now `https://heimdall.myserver.lan` resolves correctly to `myserver.lan` and NPM delivers the page. This is because I temporarily changed the NPM port in Portainer to 80:80 for HTTP. I still don't know how to overcome the port issue. Heimdall at `https://myserver.lan:8444` is working and delivering a valid SSL certificate. The Scheme in NPM is set to HTTPS. But opening https://heimdall.myserver.lan shows:

> 403 Forbidden nginx/1.23.2

So my questions are: Why can I only use Port 80 for the subdomain and how can I solve the SSL problem?

Answer (score 1):

> When I click on heimdall.myserver.lan the browser opens the location correctly but no server can be found: "We can’t connect to the server at heimdall.myserver.lan."

NGINX Proxy Manager is not the problem here. It is not doing any resolving at this point – it's *your browser* that cannot resolve the domain name *of* the Proxy Manager itself.

In short the problem seems to be that you haven't created the domain in DNS at all. The configuration that you have in Proxy Manager does not do that automatically – all it does is define how requests for this domain would be handled *if* the domain existed and *if* it were successfully resolved to the proxy's address.

The domain needs to be added to your `.lan` DNS server (the `127.0.0.1:5353` on OpenWrt, whatever that is); although you currently have myserver.lan there, but that does not automatically make subdomains exist – they all need to be added separately.

If the `.lan` DNS server doesn't allow creating custom entries and is strictly DHCP-only, you might be able to create a static override in your AdGuard configuration (which looks a lot like dnsmasq configuration, really).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I thought that's the purpose of NPM - to provide a subdomain. Otherwise I would have to add a record for every subdomain, or at least add a record for a wildcard subdomain. I have no Idea where to add this. There is no option in AdGuard Home. I googled something regarding CNAME. But again, there is no option to add CNAMEs in AdGuard Home.  `127.0.0.1:5353` on OpenWrt is the default DNS server on my OpenWrt router. OpenWrt is a Linux OS for embedded devices. Can you please take a look at my setup overview and tell me where I could possibly define subdomains?

Comment: Ok, I found it. In OpenWrt on the page "Network" -> "DHCP and DNS" -> "Hostnames" -> "Add" button I added an A record. The result are 3 new lines in `/etc/config/dhcp':` `config domain` `option name 'heimdall.myserver.lan'` `option ip '192.168.1.100'`. The server can be reached to. There is no longer a `NXDOMAIN` in tcpdump of the router. However, the destination port in NPM is ignored. The location `heimdall.myserver.lan`opens but shows the content of `http://myserver.lan(:80)` instead of `https://myserver.lan:8444`.

Comment: You're still not talking to NPM at all yet. It's running on port 8185, but a URL without any port specified always leads to port 80 (or 443).

Comment: @kamikater: It sounds as if you're assuming that NPM can somehow "pull" traffic towards it just by existing. It cannot. A proxy server is just like any other server; traffic has to be directed to it – if browsers use DNS to resolve domain names, then yes, that means you must have those domain names in DNS. If browsers attempt to connect to a specific port, then the service you want (NPM) has to be on that port.

Comment: To clarify, these are the port mappings in Portainer, which I should have given in my setup overview: `8183:80` (Public HTTP Port), `8184:443` (Public HTTPS Port), `8185:81` (Admin Web Port). I think you are trying to tell me, that it didn't suffice to add the mapping from 'heimdall.myserver.lan' to '192.168.1.100' because it lacks the correct port. Which in this case should not be 8185 (Admin webpage), but 8183 or 8184 (HTTP(S)). Am I right?

Comment: Post updated because subdomain resolves now.